# Is it safe to remove read rights from all /var/log files for others?

Tags: linux, logging, access-control

Am I supposed to be able to revoke read access recursively to `/var/log/` for `others` or will it break some applications which rely on being able to read from `/var/log/` with `other` rights?

Comment: What applications do you have installed that read /var/log as another user?

Comment: @Ramhound That basically is the question. Are application developers required to gain the necessary privileges to read from /var/log/* or is it normal to expect to be able to read from /var/log/* with the other privilege?

Comment: What is preventing you from trying your idea?

Comment: @Ramhound Some application could fail silently. I guess I will do it anyway and report here later.

Answer (score 1):

Many Linux distributions give only limited access to the files under `/var/log`. However, the directories are mostly accessible.

As far as programs that use files under `var/log`, getting info for last logins with `last` requires (read) access to `/var/log/wtmp`, so revoking access would break that functionality.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out to me. Nevertheless I think that is expected behavior because `/usr/bin/last` tries to access `/var/log/lastlog` with the permissions of the caller. If executed as root or a member of utmp in Ubuntu `last` is still able to perform.